# Using static const structs to group related class constants (C++11)

Tags: c++, c++11

What are the (dis)advantages of using the following (A):

```
// .h
class SomeClass
{
    static const struct ConstantGroup
    {
        int a = 1;
        string b = "b";
        // ... etc.
    } CONSTANT;
};
// .cpp
const SomeClass::ConstantGroup SomeClass::CONSTANT;
```

Versus (B):

```
// .h
class SomeClass
{
    static const int A;
    static const string B;
    // .. etc.
};
// .cpp
const int SomeClass::A = 1;
const string SomeClass::B = "b";
```

...for some group(s) of related static class constants? Assume no templates are involved and that the constants contain simple types (POD or strings).

So far I see the following advantages in favor of (A):

- <s>Related constants can be passed around as a group</s> EDIT: As was pointed out in the comments, this is not generally desired.
- Given that the constants are often accessed together, we can create shorthands for the structure to improve readability when needed, i.e.: `static const auto & SHORTHAND = SomeClass::LONG_NAME_FOR_CONSTANTS;`

What are the disadvantages, gotcha's, or other things to keep in mind when using this pattern?

Comment: For the first example ("A") you introduce a new scope for the constants (which aren't really *constant* themselves, and the structure is instantiable). And realistically, with a good optimizing compilers, both would probably be just about the same, you have to compare the assembly output from both to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I also think it's mostly a question of readability. I would be surprised if the generated code was significantly different.

Comment: Note that constexpr should be use in modern c++ to declare constants : `static constexpr int a = 1;`

Comment: `std::string` is not a simple type and defining one will involve a runtime initialiser so you might prefer to use `constexpr char *` instead.

Comment: @PaulSanders ... or `constexpr std::string_view`.

Comment: Why would you "pass around" global constants?

Comment: @HenriMenke Won't that still involve a static initialiser?

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm not sure what you mean by static initalizer.  With `std::string_view` you can initialize static member variables inline: `struct A { static constexpr std::string_view b = "b"; };`

Comment: @HenriMenke Sure, but that still involves constructing an object, no?, and that has to happen on program startup (by calling the appropriate constructor behind the scenes).  There can, in turn, be timing issues with that as the order in which this happens across compilation units is undefined.

Comment: @PaulSanders No, you can access `A::b` without an object (because it's static).  The second thing you note is known as the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) but this doesn't matter because the string literal `"b"` does not depend on other static objects being constructed before.  In general, if you initialized all statics with literals you never run into the static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: @HenriMenke You sure?  In what way does  a `std::string_view` differ from a `std::string` in this regard? (Because I know for a fact that a `std::string` has to be constructed at runtime, even if it's statically initialised).

Comment: @PaulSanders Please see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view and http://eel.is/c++draft/string.view

Comment: @Henri Ah, I see.  It's defined `constexpr `, that explains it, thanks.  I posted a brief answer below because I think this is interesting / useful.

Comment: @M.M In my use case these are static class constants and not necessarily public, but you're right, generally you wouldn't want to pass them around. The only reasons I can think of relate to templates or maybe `void *`. I think it mostly comes down to readability and semantics in the end.

Answer (score 6):

(A) might be harder to optimize by removing unnecessary variables from the final executable.

If you want to group constants, then consider using a `namespace` for that purpose.

```
namespace ConstantGroup
{
    constexpr int a = 1;

    // Here best solution might depend on usage and c++ version
    const std::string b;    
}
```

Passing constants as a group really does not make much sense. If something is really constant, then you need a single definition and always use it.

Also if the constant is very specific to one class, then make it a (static) member of that class.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for this when we're talking about static class constants that are applicable only to the context of a class and others derived from it?

Comment: Since a constant is constant, usually you don’t really need to hide or restrict its access. If you want it to be available to derived classes, then make it protected in a base class. Needing both protection and grouping should rarely be an issue.

Comment: It is not an issue at all. It is merely a question of semantics, readability, and C++'s expressiveness. Basically what I'm curious about is a hypothetical "namespaces in class scope" feature. Leave aside for a moment whether it is generally useful, my question is whether its emulation in the way I proposed has some hidden strong/weakpoints that I'm unaware of.

Comment: A language like C++ is intended for real-world development… so for a feature to be added to the language, it have to be useful (and passing a group of global constants around is not one of them). I would either us (B) or a `namespace` as suggested in my answer if I want to define many related constants (like seconds per minute, seconds per days, minutes per hour…) if in my application I often need that kind of constants. Otherwise, I would use constants appropriately scoped (class or function level). I don't think that (A) could ever be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting (following on from a conversation in the comments above with @Henri Menke about `string`s and `string_view`s).

Given this:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

static const std::string a = "a";
static const std::string_view b = "b";

int main ()
{
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    std::cout << b << "\n";
}
```

You can clearly see at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/FqM1wQ) that constructing `a` requires a runtime initialiser whereas `b` is a compile-time constant.

If you don't [like] read[ing] the code generated by the compiler, then try changing both `const`s to `constexpr`s.  Then, `std::string_view` still compiles but `std::string` does not.

So, for static and / or global constant strings, `constexpr std::string_view = "blah blah blah";` looks to be a good solution here as Henri says because it offers quite a bit of [extra functionality](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) over a good old-fashioned C-string, **IF** you can use C++17 **AND** you don't mind the cost of converting these to `std::string`s (which will involve constructing one) in contexts where that is what is needed at that point in the code.

If not, you are forced back to `std::string` or perhaps plain old C-strings.

---

**Edit:**

I noticed a strange shortcoming in `std::stringview` while looking into this: it offers no `operator std::string ()` method.  I've no idea why not but it means, for example, that the following won't compile:

```
void foo (std::string s)
{
    ...
}

std::string_view sv = ...;
foo (sv);
```

This is not good enough say I, so in a spirit of sharing (if anyone's still reading at this point), I humbly offer you this:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

template <class T> struct MyBasicStringView : public std::basic_string_view <T>
{
    constexpr MyBasicStringView (const T *s) : std::basic_string_view <T> (s) { }
    operator std::basic_string <T> () const { return std::basic_string <T> (this->data ()); }
};

using MyStringView = MyBasicStringView <char>;
```

Test program:

```
static constexpr MyStringView a_static_string_view = "static_string";

std::string foo (std::string s)
{
    return s + " x";
}

#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << a_static_string_view << "\n";
    MyStringView sv = "abcde";
    std::cout << sv << "\n";
    std::cout << foo (sv) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
static_string
abcde
abcde x
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E7aasuQkOiPuharj).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm bound to C++11. As for `string` vs `constexpr char *`. I think the construction cost is negligible. Since these constants are very likely to be passed through methods and operators acting on `string` I rather construct them just once. Also, I would prefer to have the full utility of `string` at my disposal, so that I may for example compare (`==`) values straightaway and not addresses.

Comment: OK, makes sense. I have amended my answer slightly.