# Is it a good practice to group related constants using structs in C?

Tags: c, struct, constants

I was wondering if it would be a good idea to use structs as pseudo namespaces (à la C++) to group constants which are functionally or conceptually related to each other.

```
static const struct {

    const unsigned int START;
    const unsigned int END;

} COUNTER = {.START = 1, .END = 100};
```

Is there any downside to this? If not, is it redundant (or maybe even unconvenient) to have both the struct instance and its members declared as `const`? Where should the constantness of these values be stated?

Comment: The `const` are redundant, a `const struct` means that all members are `const`.

Comment: why not enums ?

Comment: @bolov Because enums does not fill the purpose of emulating namespaces.

Comment: @bolov No reason, I've actually always used those for this kind of purpose. I'm basically asking this just out of curiosity. Also, maybe it is a bit of a stretch, but what if there were a couple of related, constant strings which a program needed to be readily available? Enums can't group anything behind numerals.

Comment: Have you considered `#define COUNTER_START 1` ?

Comment: @4386427 How does that emulate namespaces?

Comment: @klutt By EMULATEDNAMESPACE_NAME It's not much different from EMULATEDNAMESPACE.NAME

Comment: @4386427 True. My bad.

Comment: No downside.  Good idea.  (except redundant `const` and UPPERCASE)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica may I ask you an opinion on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078691/is-it-a-good-practice-to-group-related-constants-using-structs-in-c?noredirect=1#comment108059563_61079379

Comment: gian Micro-optimization. Now the executable is 1M + 4, rather than an optimized 1M.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if it would be a good idea to use structs as pseudo namespaces

Well, it CAN be a good idea. It's not intrinsically bad. An argument against is that if you feel that you need namespaces, then it's likely that C is the wrong language in the first place. But it can be used this way, and it is sometimes used this way.

> Where should the constantness of these values be stated?

It's in general enough to declare the whole struct as const. But beware with pointers. This code is valid and will print "42":

```
int x = 5;

const struct {
        int *p;
} S = {.p = &x };

int main()
{
        *(S.p) = 42;
        printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

In the above code, you are not allowed to change S.p so that it points to something else, but there is a difference between a const pointer and a pointer to const. So for pointer, it could be a good idea to add an extra const.

To clarify, the pointer `p` will be declared like it was a `int * const p` which means you cannot change the pointer itself, but in order to protect the data it's pointing to, you need `const int *p`. To get both, use `const int * const p`, but if the struct is declared as const, you'll get one of them "for free" so `const int *p` is enough to get both.

And if you consider pointers to pointers, well, think it through for a long time and test it to make sure it works the way you want.

From comments:

> Why not enums?

Because this is not valid:

```
enum S {a = 5};
enum Y {a = 6};
```

The compiler will tell you that `a` is already defined. So enums is not good for emulating namespaces. Also, you cannot use enums for non-integers.

Comment: So, basically there's nothing wrong in doing this, but cases were it may be actually useful are rare and for most purposes using enums is more than adeguate?

Comment: @Gian Hmmm, don't really know how to answer that. If enums are suitable, then structs are not and vice versa. They are different things with different purposes.

Comment: what I meant is that, as has been pointed out, there isn't much difference between NAMESPACE.constant and NAMESPACE_CONSTANT. So in this sense enums and structs can be used interchangeably and it just so happens that enums are more convenient.

Comment: Found a kind of similiar question about C++. Don't know it this applies to C as well, but a user suggests that doing this might prevent the compiler to optimize out unused named values, because they're part of a name which, as whole, has been used by the program and then allocated in its entirety https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51162789/using-static-const-structs-to-group-related-class-constants-c11#comment89318441_51164586 So maybe that's another argument against using structs this way?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a good practice to group related constants using structs in C?

It's opinion based. If it works for you, do it.

I wouldn't do like that i C. Instead I use `#define`

Like:

```
#define GROUPNAME_NAME
```

so in your case I would do

```
#define COUNTER_START 1
#define COUNTER_END 100
```

In C++ I would do:

```
const unsigned int COUNTER_START = 1;
const unsigned int COUNTER_END = 100;
```

The difference between C and C++ is due to differences in language specification.